# How to merge two branches in Git, but keep all differences on both and resolve conflicts manually

Tags: git, merge

So my git branches are set up as follows:

```
      -------- A
    /           \
master -------- master
    \
      --------------------B
```

As in, I branched A and B from master at the same time, and have since merged A back into master and deleted branch A. On branch A, I deleted some code that still exists on branch B. For example, On branch master I have (just an example):

```
class Eg {
  int a;
}
```

On branch B, I have:

```
class Eg {
  unsigned int b;
}
```

which is what existed on master before I branched A and B.

I have since realised that I need both, i.e. I need:

```
class Eg {
  int a;
  unsigned int b;
}
```

When I try to merge master into B, I end up losing `unsigned int B` (because branch B is behind master for changes to that section). Is there a way to keep changes from both, and manually resolve everything? I.e., after merge, end up with:

```
class Eg {
<<<
  int a;
===
  unsigned int b;
>>>
}
```

on branch B, and resolve all of these by hand? I need all changes from branch A/master, AND some of the changes from the older version of master that I overwrote on branch A, which still exist on branch B (and I need all my changes on branch B since I've branched from master). I realise this is quite a mess I've made, so I don't mind manually resolving everything (the changes on A are small enough that resolving conflicts by hand is fine).

Comment: What about interactive rebase?

Comment: @Ashot I initially tried that, but only ended up getting partway through before giving up because of how many commits are on what used to be branch A. (The commits don't have a lot of content, but there's lots of them). I was hoping to just dump all the changes together and resolve by hand since the actual changes are minimal, but might end up having to rebase if there's no other choices.

Comment: Rebase is the best choice in your case, with interactivity, you have control over the individual commits, you travel back and start applying commit by commit. I know it might take too long, but it is safe.  Other option would be squashing commits on master (or clone of master) from the point you created your branch A to the last made commit if you have access to do it. It will make the rebasing process fast, but still, you have to fix conflicts like in case of a merge.

Answer (score 0):

The change that is busting you is coming from A.... in order to correct it *elegantly*, before you merge it, you could add the line to master.... or you could revert (on master) the revision where that line was changed on A (if there are no other changes on that revision)... or you could checkout A (even if the branch does not exist, it's irrelevant), add the line, then merge again into master.... anyway, have master have this content with any trick you might like to use in your workflow):

```
class Eg {
  int a;
  unsigned int b;
}
```

Then, when you merge B, you will get the stuff you want there.

Comment: I have lots of changes, I don't want to have to manually add each one into master without any help from git

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that there is more than one little thing that is disappearing when you do the merge, so simply doing the merge and correcting the issue is likely not the best approach. That being said another approach may be to clone a second copy of the repository, such that you have the files from both B and master and then use a tool such as Beyond Compare to merge the two branches manually and save those changes. On the copy that you did not change (assuming it would be the one with branch B checked out) do the merge and then you can compare the changes back to branch B. Not an elegant solution, but  if you have some complicated changes and lots of files, it may be worth it.

Comment: yes, in my question I just included one example. There are many little things that are changed, and forgetting one would be bad, which is why I was hoping for a nice solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, this would be the easiest way that I would know to do this. The good thing about this solution is a tool such as beyond compare can compare all files between the two branches and ensure that you have manually merged everything. The other reason I suggest this tool specifically is that unlike Win Merge you can actually tell it to ignore specific folders, white space, and creation date differences.